# Target overriding in Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, build.xml

Is there a possibility to literally override a target or emulate this somehow?

So, when I call

```
<target perform-after="release">
     <do-something />
</target>
```

It will act like this:

```
<target name="release">
     <antcall target="release" /> <!-- call previous version, not recursion -->
     <do-something /> 
</target>
```

I think it has a meaning, I'll describe on Android example:

We have an `.xml` templates for every `build.xml` in SDK folder (`{$SDK}/tools/ant/*.xml`), these files are included in every generated `build.xml` for each project. There are only `-pre-compile`, `-pre-build` and `-post-compile` targets that empty and easy to override. But there is no empty `-post-release` target, for example. Google recommends in generated `build.xml` comments just to copy-paste a target to my own `build.xml` and then tune it. But I think it is not ok, because if Google will change something in this target inside a template, I will never know about I am using outdated version.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See the "Target overriding" section of the [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) task or the "Target rewriting" section of the [include](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html) task.  In short, give the common build.xml a project name like "common", and then use "common.release" in the antcall.

I'll note that antcall isn't quite the same since it starts a new project at runtime, which means variables set by the target won't be visible later.  I don't have Ant available on this machine to test, but you might try something like this to avoid the antcall:

```
<target name="release" depends="common.release, -post-release"/>
```

Comment: Cool, that's the thing I've wanted and no-one answered to me) Thank you!