# How to redefine target in Ant?

Tags: java, xml, ant

file1.xml

```
<project name="main_file">
  <import file="file2.xml"/>
  ...
</project>
```

file2.xml

```
<project name="inc_file">
  <target name="target1">
    ... 
  </target>
</project>
```

Can I redefine `inc_file.target1` in `file1.xml`? Target in `main_file` should be called instead of `inc_file.target1`.

**UPD**: I didn't want the old target was called. I would like to get a new target replaced the old

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target overriding in Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979583/target-overriding-in-ant)

Comment: @dnault I didn't want the old target was called. I would like to get a new target replaced the old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Ant documentation for [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) task. It explains clearly that `import` behave like you expect (see subsection *Target overriding*): just redefine your `target1` target in `main_file` and it will override the one defined in `inc_file`.